# Oracle Apex Authentication Mechanism

Tags: wcf, authentication, oracle-apex

I am a newbie to oracle apex and I need to know the authentication mechanism performed by Oracle Apex.
Basically, I am using LDAP authentication and once the user/pwd is authenticated, no more authentication is done until session expires.

The process is built in, can anyone let me know what happens after its authenticated like creating cookies/session or any other mechanism?

The idea is to integrate asp.net website with Oracle apex(in iframe). The login page will exist in asp.net website and once the user clicks submit button both asp.net website and Oracle apex should process authentication mechanism.

I have already done with windows authentication and need to explore more options (like ldap authentication, integrating WCF/webservice authentication) . Upvote for helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option might be to use the Thoth Gateway and use windows integrated authentication.  See the section "Features in Thoth that are not in mod_plsql" at

https://github.com/mortenbra/thoth-gateway

snippet from site:
Integrated Windows authentication (if the virtual directory that contains the Thoth Gateway is set up with integrated Windows authentication, you can get the username of the authenticated user via owa_util.get_cgi_env('LOGON_USER'))

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/sec_authentication.htm) from the APEX documentation explains the process of user authentication and guides you through the available options.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is "session management".  After a very brief glance at [Oracle's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/concept_ses.htm), it looks like the Oracle Apex server generates a session ID, which is passed over the underlying http(s) channel as part of the URI.  Oracle docs also talk about session timeout and similar stuff.